# Iterating Values in Angular 9 from LocalStorage

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-forms, angular-ngfor

I have a problem displaying a nested value from Localstorage in Angular. The problem is on the second *ngFor. The first *ngFor display well. The second ngFor has an error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined"? I don't know why the is toUppercase since i didn't use uppercase here

[image: PIC]

**HTML**

```
<mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let bookmark of bookmarks">
     {{ extractNameFromJson(bookmark[1]).id }}
         <ul>
           <li *ngFor="let extractNameFromJson(bookmark[1])?.cuesData of bookmark">
                   {{ }}   
            </li>
         </ul>
 </mat-list-item>
```

**TS**

```
 getAllBookmarks() {
   this.bookmarks = Object.entries(localStorage);
   console.log(this.bookmarks);
 }

 extractNameFromJson(obj) {
    obj = JSON.parse(obj);
    return obj;
  }
```

Comment: What's the data structure of `bookmark`?

Comment: @T.SunilRao. Pls check edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value of each bookMark as a variable in `*ngFor` first. You cannot have a function call while extracting a variable from a loop using `ngFor`. One way can be to have a `pipe` which does this filtering for you while looping, or another way could be to use `ng-container` to loop and only show `lis` if your condtion passes.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let eachBookMark of bookmark">
    <ng-container *ngIf="extractNameFromJson(eachBookMark[1]) as data">
        <ng-container *ngIf="data.cuesData">
            <li *ngFor="data.cuesData">
                {{data | json}}
            </li>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

**EDIT:**
if you want to change the `bookmarks` array in your ts, maybe you can do this:

```
this.bookmarks = this.bookmarks.map(([first, second]) => {
    return [first, JSON.parse(second)];
});
```

Now, if you have done this, then your HTML can be simply:

```
<mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let eachBookMark of bookmarks">
    <ul>
        <ng-container *ngIf="eachBookMark[1].cuesData as cuesData">
            <li *ngFor="let eachCue of cuesData">
                {{ eachCue.description }}   
            </li>
        </ng-container>
    </ul>
</mat-list-item>
```

**EDIT2:**

```
this.filteredBookmarks = this.bookmarks.reduce((acc, [first, second]) => {
    const parsedOb = JSON.parse(second);
    if (parsedOb.cuesData) {
        acc.push([first, parsedOb]);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

<mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let eachBookMark of filteredBookmarks">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let eachCue of cuesData">
                {{ eachCue.description }}   
        </li>
    </ul>
</mat-list-item>
```

All the above filtering, (map/reduce) would happen at the place where you are populating `bookmarks`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me transform this already into the TS file? So i won't do this extractNameFromJson() function in HTML. Thanks

Comment: @Joseph If you want to convert the second element as an object in your ts and store it in the same array yhen you can use the update. If you want to mantain a different array to maintain the converted objects, you can do that too.

Comment: Can you rewrite it into TS ? Pls also revise your HTML. Just edit your answer here. Thanks

Comment: @Joseph Done, added one approach. Another way could be to use a `Array.filter()` in ts, instead of `map` and only return the arrays which have `cuesData`, this would not require an extra check in `ng-container`. It depends on you whatever you feel right for your app.

Comment: @Joseph Done with the final edit, I think you can take care from here.

Comment: Thanks. Which do you suggest to use? I want the best and fasters performance?

Comment: @Joseph I do not think, performance wouldn't matter much in any of them. It depends upon your requirement which one you pick. Do you you have a requirement in parsed Object to be reused? For a cleaner code I would go with 2nd approach, but it totally depends on your full app requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Update as requested**

TS:

```
 getAllBookmarks() {
   this.bookmarks = this.extractNameFromJson(Object.entries(localStorage));
   console.log(this.bookmarks);
 }

 extractNameFromJson(obj) {
   obj = JSON.parse(obj);
   return obj;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let bookmark of bookmarks">
  {{ bookmark[1].id }}
  <ul *ngIf="bookmark[1].cuesData>
    <li *ngFor="let cue of bookmark[1].cuesData">
      {{ cue.description }}   
    </li>
  </ul>
</mat-list-item>
```

**Original Answer**

The second `*ngFor` syntax is incorrect

Inferred from what you have posted, this is what you need.

Update: added function `extractNameFromJson`

```
     <ul *ngIf="bookmark[1].cuesData">
       <li *ngFor="let cue of extractNameFromJson(bookmark[1].cuesData)">
         {{ cue.description }}   
       </li>
     </ul>
```

Assumed you need to show `description` from the screenshot, you can show `startTime` or `endTime` as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think you forgot to put extractNameFromJson()? It isnt displaying. By the way, can you help me transform this already into the TS file? So i won't do this extractNameFromJson() function in HTML. Thanks

Comment: Added function `extractNameFromJson()`

Comment: converting in TS would be better.

Comment: Pls convert it to TS. Your html here is not displaying.

Comment: Check the whole thing now.